# name cytoscape's nodes by primary key in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, nodes, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I'm trying to display a network using `cytoscape` based on a `mysql` database, I've got two tables, one contains the name (`device_id`), `ip` and `SN` that means serial number (PK) of each device in the network, the otherone has relation's info: `origin's SN` `destiny's SN`, `interface` and `port`.

I've made those three querys:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dispositivos';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());
$numdispositivos = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

then I've tried to make a for loop to create the nodes based on the number of rows at the table:

```
 var numerodispositivos = "<?php echo $numdispositivos; ?>";
```

using this loop im drawing nodes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numerodispositivos; i++) {
            cy.add({
                data: { id: 'node' + i }
                }
            );
            var source = 'node' + i;
            cy.add({
                data: {
                    id: 'edge' + i,
                    source: source,
                    target: (i % 2 == 0 ? 'a' : 'b')
                }
            });
```

I would like to name those nodes with the primary key of "dispositivos" but i don't know how to iterate through the table row by row or how to extract that info.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an array that includes your primary key in `php` instead of just the number of rows (you'll need to specify what your primary key is):

```
$j=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $primary_key = $row["PRIMARY_KEY"];
    $php_array[$primary_key] = $j;
    $j++;
}

$json_from_php = json_encode($php_array);
```

Th resulting JSON array could then be echo'd in JS (where `i` is your primary key in the loop), allowing you to run a `for` loop that you could then pull primary key strings/numbers from:

```
var jsonArray = "<?php echo $json_from_php; ?>";

for (var i in jsonArray) {
    cy.add({
        data: { id: i }
        }
    );
    var source = i;
    cy.add({
        data: {
            id: i,
            source: source,
            target: (jsonArray[i] % 2 == 0 ? 'a' : 'b')
        }
    });
}
```

You probably also want to move to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.